# I cannot make a cast from unbounded wildcard to a specific List<Game>

Tags: list, casting, wildcard

I tried this in my controller class:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {


    try {
        games = (List<?>) fr.readFile();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<GameImpl> games2 = (List<GameImpl>) games;


    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("err");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

but when I try to access games2 function, an Exception occurred

Comment: What was the exception message? You are reading into a untyped list, and then attempting a conversion to a list of <GameImpl> and that cant be done. What is the definition of GameImpl?  and the contents of the fr.readfile?  (just share the column headers or the first row)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.